# How to pass multidimensional values to a json array?

Tags: json, multidimensional-array

I am trying to pass the value to an api through json request.

```
  $payload = json_encode( array("phones"=> "971xxxxxxx",
"emails"=> "fadfad@xyz.com",
"id"=> "1"
  ) );
```

How will i pass the below multi dimensional values to a json request like the above code?

```
 { "contactList": [ { "phones" : ["+91 9000000034"], "emails" : [fadfad@xyz.com], "id" : 1 }, { "phones" : ["+91 903-310-00-001"], "emails" : [krs@xyz.in], "id" : 2 } ] }
```

Comment: use `json_encode(array('contactList' => array( array('phone'=> 'xxxx'), array('phone' => 'dgdfs') ) ) );`

Comment: also if we have a format like { "contactList":[ "22", "46" ], "conferenceId":167 } ,how will we do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the data as nested / multidimensional arrays before passing it to json_encode.

```
$array = array();
$array["contactList"] = array(
array(  "phones"=> "971xxxxxxx",
        "emails"=> "fadfad@xyz.com",
        "id"=> "1"
    ),
array(  "phones"=> "+91 903-310-00-001",
        "emails"=> "krs@xyz.in",
        "id"=> "2"
    )
);     

$payload = json_encode($array);

echo $payload;
```

produces

```
{"contactList":[{"phones":"971xxxxxxx","emails":"fadfad@xyz.com","id":"1"},{"phones":"+91 903-310-00-001","emails":"krs@xyz.in","id":"2"}]}
```

If you need to hold values like the phone numbers inside an array, simply wrap them in an array.

Comment: also if we have a format like { "contactList":[ "22", "46" ], "conferenceId":167 } ,how will we do it?

Comment: You would have to store the contact list value as an array of values, but the conference ID as a single value. In this specific instance you would ensure the data type was int so you don't get the string quotes applied. You can cast if converting from a data source.